# Error "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" when trying to delete an entity containing a OneToMany relation

Tags: database, sqlite, typeorm, capacitor

When I try to delete an entity that contains a OneToMany relation, I get an error on the console:

```
query failed:  DELETE FROM "task_group_entity" WHERE "id" = ? -- PARAMETERS: ["63361153-83cc-49b8-ba12-19f54e0519a2"]
error:  Error: Run: RunSQL: run: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I am using capacitor-sqlite+typeorm.

Here's my entity code:

Relationship owner side:

```
@Entity()
export class TaskGroupEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column('datetime', { nullable: true })
    dayTaskDate: Date | null;

    @Column('text', { nullable: true })
    name: string | null;

    @Column('text', { nullable: true })
    description: string | null;

    @OneToMany(() => TaskEntity, task => task.taskGroup, { nullable: true, cascade: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    tasks: (TaskEntity | null)[];

    @Column('text', { nullable: true })
    color: string | null;

    @Column('text', { nullable: true })
    icon: string | null;

    // Already added cascade: true on the other side of the relationship, this column doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem
    @ManyToMany(() => TagEntity, tag => tag.taskGroups, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable()
    tags: (TagEntity | null)[];

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createDate: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deleteDate: Date;

    @Column('datetime', { nullable: true })
    deadLineDate: Date | null;

    @Column('text')
    repeatMode: RepeatMode;

    @Column('simple-json', { nullable: true })
    repeatCustom: RepeatCustom | null;

}
```

The other side of the relation:

```
@Entity()
export class TaskEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(() => TaskGroupEntity, taskGroup => taskGroup.tasks, { nullable: true })
    taskGroup: TaskGroupEntity | null;

    @ManyToOne(() => TaskEntity, task => task.childTasks, { nullable: true })
    parentTask: TaskEntity | null;

    @OneToMany(() => TaskEntity, task => task.parentTask, { nullable: true })
    childTasks: TaskEntity[] | null[];

}
```

I tried searching for a solution in Google and someone mentioned to specify onDelete: "CASCADE" in the OneToMany annotation. But when I tried it, it still reported an error.

Then I tried to set onDelete to SET NULL and it still reported an error.

Then I tried to delete the entity using softDelete and it worked.

But when I tried to hardDelete the entity, the error came back.

Then I tried deleting the entity with no containment relationship (i.e. the column is an empty array) and no error was reported.

I'm new to SQL, how do I properly delete an entity that contains a OneToMany relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I realized that I was very stupid and had to add `onDelete: "CASCADE"` to both sides of the relationship for the cascade to work correctly.

Comment: I was about to write an answer explaining this, but it's good that your found it out yourself.